# how to get quarter information like last,current,next quarter using shell script likewise -- 2017q4,2018q1,2018q2

Tags: shell-script

how to get quarter information like last,current,next quarter using shell script
 likewise -- 2017q4,2018q1,2018q2

Comment: is this `2017q4,2018q1,2018q2` your input string or expected result?

Comment: expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it using bash:

```
declare -i m=$(date +%m)
declare -i cq=($m-1)/3+1
declare -i cy=$(date +%Y)
declare -i py=$cy; [ $m -lt 4 ] && py=$cy-1
declare -i pq=$cq-1; [ $pq -eq 0 ] && pq=4
declare -i ny=$cy; [ $m -gt 9 ] && ny=$cy+1
declare -i nq=$cq+1; [ $nq -gt 4 ] && nq=1
echo ${py}q${pq},${cy}q${cq},${ny}q${nq}
```

ex for now: 2018q1,2018q2,2018q3

Answer (score 0):

```
month=$(date +%m)
quarter=$(( (2 + 10#$month) / 3 ))
```

demo

```
for m in {1..12}; do 
    read y m < <(date -d "2018-$m-1" "+%Y %m")
    printf "%s-%s is in q%d\n" "$y" "$m" "$(( (2 + 10#$m) / 3))"
done
```

```
2018-01 is in q1
2018-02 is in q1
2018-03 is in q1
2018-04 is in q2
2018-05 is in q2
2018-06 is in q2
2018-07 is in q3
2018-08 is in q3
2018-09 is in q3
2018-10 is in q4
2018-11 is in q4
2018-12 is in q4
```

We need to use `10#$month` in the arithmetic expression because otherwise `08` and `09` will throw "invalid octal number" errors.